# Grayscale Image to SVG in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, svg, vector

I have a a grayscale image in the form of a numpy array. I want to use the pixel values to draw a svg image by using python.

I know about pypotrace, however I am facing lot of difficulties to install it. If you can come up with a different type of solution, it would be great.

My grayscale image looks like below:

[image]

Comment: `Matplotlib` allows you to save image arrays in `SVG` format

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked 12 days ago, I wrote a port of potrace directly in python. Which would correct a lot of the install issues with `pypotrace`.

https://github.com/tatarize/potrace
pip install potracer

Should use a nearly identical api as pypotrace.